# How do I centre my title properly

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

The title "NAME" seems to be shifted slightly to the right when I use this code, is there a fix to this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{res} %Sets the default text size to 11pt and class to article.

%------------------------Dimensions--------------------------------------------

\begin{document} 
%These two pieces of code tell LaTeX that everything that goes in between these tags is what you want displayed as your actual document.
\centerline{{\Huge \sc NAME} }  %Makes whatever text you put in parenthesis move to the center

%Prevents the following text from being indented
%This is the same as a return in Latex
\centerline{124 derp Ave\textbullet \hspace{5pt}  Somewhere,Somewhere \textbullet \hspace{5pt}6125 396 448} 
\centerline{random8@hotmail.com} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. Note that indenting code by 4 spaces makes it more readable. The easiest way is to select it and press the '{}' button. `\centerline` is probably not what you want and is deprecated for most use. You might want `\title{NAME}` in your preamble (the bit before `\begin{document}`) or you might prefer `{\centering\Huge\scshape NAME\\}` or `\begin{center}\Huge\scshape NAME\end{center}`. Don't use `\sc` - that command is obsolete. Either say `\scshape` or `\textsc{small amount of text}`.

Comment: Actually, it is slightly left of center when I try it. This can be traced to the extra space after `NAME` in `\centerline{{\Huge \sc NAME} }`

Answer (score 3):

Just for example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}% Sets the default text size to 11pt and class to article.
\usepackage{url}% format urls nicely
%------------------------Dimensions--------------------------------------------
\title{Name As Title}
\date{}% if you don't want an automatic date
% \author{}% if you need an author

\begin{document}
% \maketitle% format title, author and date (if specified) - possibly not for a CV, though

{\par\centering\Huge\scshape Name with \verb|\centering|\par}

\begin{center}
    \Huge\scshape Name in \verb|center| environment
\end{center}

{\par\centering
  124 derp Ave\textbullet \hspace{5pt}  Somewhere,Somewhere \textbullet \hspace{5pt}6125 396 448\\
  \url{random8@hotmail.com}\par}
\end{document}
```

will give you:

[image: sample of <code>\centering</code> and <code>center</code>]

Comment: @jon You know, I think you are right. Though I don't know or have forgotten why. (And I am so in the habit of using `\\` that I never think to use `\par`.)